# Is it possible INDEXING on PARTITIONS...?

Tags: mysql

I have been looking a way to optimise one of my queries.
currently it is using PARTITONS and the INDEX for look ups. It is scanning 23Mill rows in the partitions. I would like to add an index on the available partitions.

Do we have a chance to add an index on a specific partition in MYSQL....?

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning applies to all data and indexes of a table; you cannot partition only the data and not the indexes, or vice versa, nor can you partition only a portion of the table. Indexes are partitioned along the data.

You can use `LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE`  for specific partition.

For more information:

-[partitioning overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)

-[LOAD INDEX INTO CACHE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-index.html)